# Clickable link on bg-image

Tags: html, css

This problem bothering me very long, and I try to figure the solution, but I just can get it.

I have `background image` on div tag, and on that image I have part with text, which I want to select to be a link.

So I try it this way `#signUp` is a a element which is positioned in div `#main_text`:

```
#signUp {
   display:block;
   width:137px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   left:31px;
   top:289px;
}

#main_text {
  width: 840px;
  height: 335px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

The problem is that this code works fine in all browsers excepting the IE, on IE `signUP` is not clickable, any solutions, thanks.

This is html part :

```
<div id="main_text">
<?php if (function_exists("easing_slider")){ easing_slider(); }; ?><a href = "#" id="signUp" class="eModal eModal-1"></a>     
</div>
```

Comment: would you mind to create a jsfiddle to see?

Comment: Which IE are you using? IE 6-8 or IE 9+?

Comment: What is `#signUp`? An anchor?

Comment: Post the HTML code also... is difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: It seems it works well on IE 9: http://jsfiddle.net/bcC3w/3/

Comment: strange, why are all the browsers so diffirent ??? Everybody thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, it would be a bit more flexible if you changed `#singUp`'s `top: 289px;` to `bottom: 0px;`. It's kinda hard to say without seeing the problem, but what if you try to inspect the non-clickable link and see if there's maybe another transparent element on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the mentioned below code its working on IE also IE8+

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_text">
    <a href = "#" target="_blank" id="signUp" class="eModal eModal-1">Sign Up</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#signUp {
   display:inline-block;
   width:137px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   left:31px;
   top:289px;
   background:red;
   color:black;
   text-align:center;

}

#main_text {
  width: 840px;
  height: 335px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/GwE0olI7)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work in IE6, IE7 and newer. http://jsfiddle.net/uPeWh/
I think the problem was the z-index of the containers.

```
#signUp {
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    font: 1em Arial;
    color: white;
}

#main_text {
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
} ​

<div id="main_text">
    <a href = "#" id="signUp" class="eModal eModal-1">Click me</a>     
</div>​
```